# Energy stability of a passively Q-switched Laser

Tags: laser

I'm working as a Laser physicist and we are trying to build/develop a passively Q-switched Laser. The only problem is that the energy stability is not satisfying for the customers purpose. I think this is mainly due to spatial hole burning -in the gain medium as well as in the saturable absorber - and the related randomly lasing longitudinal modes. My question now is, is there a preferred position to palce the saturable absorber and the gain medium within the cavity such that the energy stability is optimal - at least form a theoretical standpoint ?

I would appreciate any discussion or suggestions for literature or papers wich are dealing with this kind of problem. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything in this direction until now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the RP photonics article on SHB and refs therein? Every cavity is different, but I guess you should run some simulations. My obvious choice against SHB would be a ring cavity, but of course that's not always possible. I also have very few knowledge on an actual implementation of q-switched lasers, but I find it strange that there isn't enough literature on their proper design...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes a simulation would be nice, but I’m really not sure which set of rate equations I should use for that. Do you have any suggestions for that ?